# Why are int var added when I link these int var as string?

Tags: java, android

I hope to generate a file name based date, I think the string name will return 20151027_161053.mp4.

In fact it return 2051_161053.mp4, it seems that the year, month and day are added 2051=2015+10+27-1, but it seems that 161053 are not added.

What wrong do I made in my code? Thanks!

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sencond=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    String name;
    name=year+month+day+"_"+hour+minute+sencond+".mp4";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to retrive the name in the format you need.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", Locale.US)
String name = f.format(c.getTime());
```

You can also read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) about the java's operator precedence

Answer (score 2):

What happens is firstly you add year, month and day, then you cast it to String by appending `"_"` and then appending hour, minute and second will cause casting them to String as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is being added because int + int = int; so you need to make it int + String + int which is = String
Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int sencond=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    String name;
    name=year+""+month+""+day+"_"+hour+""+minute+""+sencond+".mp4";
```

Comment: You have solved HelloCW's logic issue. Thats good. 1+.
Atleast he knows where he is going wrong.

Comment: Yes V.J. the main purpose is not to provide a solution only, but to explain it too :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the operation `+` on `int` with following statement :

```
year+month+day+"_"+hour+minute+sencond+".mp4";
```

It is equivalent to this because you are first adding integer, then only when "_" occurs Java cast it to `String` :

```
((int) (year+month+day)) + "_" + hour + minute + sencond + ".mp4";
```

Cast your `int` to `String` first or use `String.append()` for example. There are many ways of writing this :)

**EDIT** : Or as mentionned above, use `DateFormat` wich is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

try it with

```
name = "" + year+month+day+"_"+hour+minute+sencond+".mp4";
```

Java expressions are evaluated from left to right. So with your old statement it will add ((year+month) + day). After that it will cast the sum to a string ad append `"_"` to it. Now you add a String to all those integers (hour, minute and second) thus they will be converted to string implicitely!

If you add a `"" +` at the beginning of this statement, every integer added to it will be converted into a string and appended!

Answer (score 0):

You must use `String` instead of `int`. According to the [summary of operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

> + Additive operator (also used for String concatenation)

the `+` is used to concatenate `String`. Otherwise it is used to add. So convert your `ìnt` to `String` will solve the problem

```
String year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "";
String month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "";
String day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "";
String hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "";
String minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "";
String sencond=c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "";

String name = year + month + day + "_" + hour + minute + sencond + ".mp4";
```

**EDIT**

You can also use a `StringBuilder`

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int sencond=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(year);
builder.append(month);
builder.append(day);
builder.append("_");
builder.append(hour);
builder.append(minute);
builder.append(sencond);
builder.append(".mp4");

String name = builder.toString();
```